# Barplot coming back with 'height must be a vector or matrix'

Tags: r

I've put in my `x` and `y` variables as

```
x = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, "8-14", ">14")
y = c(70, 43, 25, 10, 20, 72, 87, 32, 9)
```

When I type in command

```
barplot(y~x, mainlab= "Duration of car hire period for customers", 
  xlab= "Number of Days Rented", ylab= "Frequency")
```

It comes back with

> Error in barplot.default(y ~ x, mainlab = "Duration of car hire period for customers",  : 
>     'height' must be a vector or a matrix

Can someone explain this?

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
x= c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8-14", ">14")
y= c(70, 43, 25, 10, 20, 72, 87, 32, 9)


barplot(y, mainlab= "Duration of car hire period for customers", xlab= "Number of Days Rented", ylab= "Frequency",
        names.arg= x)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: What exactly does that function do for the barplot if you don't mind me asking? Works great thanks!

Comment: The barplot function expects a vector or a matrix containing the heights of the bars as an input.The `names.arg` part is an argument of the function `barplot` that defines the names of the bars. You can also assign the names to the vector `y`, using `names(y) <- x` and remove the `names.arg` argument. The result would be identical. Hope that helps.

Comment: @boberthood if you are happy with the answer, could you mark it as the correct one by clicking on the check symbol? :)